# Error mocking a "non-strict" legacy module on Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

I have some really messy non-strict-compliant legacy code on javascript, running just fine on **NodeJs** 12, and I'm trying to abstract it away and test the overlaying, new layers of code using **Jest/Mocks**.

But when I try to run the tests I receive the following error:

```
Test suite failed to run

SyntaxError: /legacy-path/messy_legacy_code.js: Legacy octal literals are not allowed in strict mode (557:66)
at Parser._raise (node_modules/@babel/parser/src/parser/error.js:60:45)
```

I'm trying to mock it away first thing on my test code, but still get this error. It seems that Jest is trying to parse it with Babel; it really won't find any compliant code there... It *just runs* on Node, nothing else.

I already tried mocking the legacy code itself and also tried making a container to "abstract" it away and mocking the container. But it seems Jest still tries to read every bit of noncompliant code behind it.

My `modern.test.js` code looks like this:

```js
jest.mock('../../../../legacy-path/messy-container')
const { ModernLayer } = require('../../../../modern-path/modern-module');
```

Any ideas on how I cant completely block Jest from trying to read this noncompliant code and just mock it away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jest.mock('...')` performs auto-mock, unless a mock from `__mocks__` is used. It tries to process module exports and fails on syntax error.

The module should be manually mocked instead:

```
jest.mock('../../../../legacy-path/messy-container', () => ({ ModernLayer: ... }));
```